# Build your first unlock package- Salesforce DX Badge

Tags: salesforcedx

I am trying to complete my "Build your first Unlocked package" step in the "unlocked Packages for Customers" Badge

while doing this i am getting this error[image]

The error is following:

ERROR running force:package:version:create:  AccountController: SELECT Id,Name,Active__c FROM Account WHERE Active__c
               ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:16
No such column 'Active__c' on entity 'Account'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I fail to understand whats causing this error.

Can somebody please help me through this? would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your unlocked package must be a **complete** package. This means that all dependencies must exist in your unlocked package, either directly or in a dependency. To resolve this error, simply do:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomField:Account.Active__c
```

This will add the following file:

```
force-app/main/default/objects/Account/fields/Active__c.field-meta.xml
```

Assuming no other dependencies exist, this will allow the package to to build successfully. You may need to add additional dependencies to successfully complete this package.

Comment: that solved the issue thanks for prompt reply but after moving on i got the following error:

Comment: ERROR running force:package:version:create: 
                             ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:30
sObject type 'Package2' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. 

Try this:
Packaging is not enabled on this org. Verify that you are authenticated to the desired org and try again. Otherwise, contact Salesforce Customer Support for more information.

Comment: @zsk_1 You need to enable [Dev Hub](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm&type=5) in your org, and make sure you have [the appropriate permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm). Also, make sure that the Dev Hub org is set up as the default (`sfdx force:config:set defaultdevhubusername=mydevhuborg@whateverdomain.com`).

Comment: I have already enabled my devhub org

Comment: and i am using a system administrator profile so i guess i already have permissions granted by default...

Comment: @zsk_1 Double-check and make sure you're using the right user for the command. That's definitely the error you would get if you didn't have permission. Try `sfdx force:config:list` to see that `defaultdevhubusername` is, and `sfdx force:org:list --all` to verify that username matches what you expect.

Comment: its resolved as i was using Myscratchorg rather than MyTP as devhub...Thanks alot

Comment: @zsk_1 Yeah, that's an easy mistake to make.