# Build your first unlock package

Tags: salesforcedx

I am trying to complete my "Build your first Unlocked package" step in the "unlocked Packages for Customers" Badge

While doing it, I am getting the following error:

[image]

It says:

> ERROR running force:package:install:  Invalid alias or ID:
>   dreamhouse@3.0.0-5. Either your alias is invalid or undefined, or the
>   ID provided is invalid.

Can somebody please help me through this?

Comment: This seems to be very similar to your previous question: [Build your first unlock package- Salesforce DX Badge](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/290274/build-your-first-unlock-package-salesforce-dx-badge). Can you give us a quick explanation of the differences between this one and that one?

Answer (score 0):

The instruction specifies clearly for the command to create package be

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p dreamhouse -d force-app -k test1234 --wait 10 -v DevHub
```

This bumps up or modify the version package alias

And to install you use the same command as mentioned in the trailhead instruction.

```
sfdx force:package:install --wait 10 --publishwait 10 --package dreamhouse@1.0.0-1 -k test1234 -r -u MyScratchOrg
```

I am not sure where from you are having the version dreamhouse@3.0.0.5

You also have wrong version name ( winter 19) also in your json file make sure these errors are corrected and re-attempt the badge. Following is the file from TH

```
{
   "packageDirectories": [
      {
         "path": "force-app",
         "default": true,
         "package": "dreamhouse",
         "versionName": "Version 1.0",
         "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT"
      }
   ],
   "namespace": "",
   "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
   "sourceApiVersion": "44.0",
   "packageAliases": {
      "dreamhouse": "0Hoxxx"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To install the package on your scratch org you need to specify the package name, not the version so use something like this:

```
sfdx force:package:install --wait 10 --publishwait 10 --package dreamhouse -r -u MyScratchOrg
```